# constructing or modifying scala.reflect.api.Position

Tags: reflection, scala-macros, scala-2.11

I have a macro and I can get the `pos` of a literal string.  I want my errors to highlight a subset of that string given a computed offset.  How can I construct a new sub position base on the old position?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow our progress with https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8063 for more information.